# Calculating Driving distance for 70000 different locations by using only Longitude and Latitude

Tags: r, google-maps, rstudio, latitude-longitude, bing-maps

I need to calculate a driving distance from location A to Location B, by using Long and Lat only. Ggmaps are no good, since they are blocking their service after 2500 searches, and I need 70 000 calculations. I tried to use Bing maps, got the API key, but my code in R studio doesn't seem to be the right one. So I have:

1. Rstudio
2. A LOT of long and lat to be calculated
3. API key for bing maps
4. R code that doesn't work.

Does anybody know how I can automate that process?

Any help will be appreciated. Konstantin
here is the code:

```
DF <- read.csv("clipboard", header=T, sep ="\t", quote = "", row.names =            NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

View(DF)

Plant.name <- DF[ ,1]
Plant.City <- DF[ ,2]
Postal.code <- DF[ ,3]
Country.plant <- DF[ ,4]
Plant.lat <- DF[ ,5]
Plant.long <- DF[ ,6]
NU <- DF[ , 7]
TS.level.2.code <- DF[ ,8]
NUTS.level.2.city <- DF[ ,9]
NUTS.level.2.label <- DF[ ,10]
NUTS.level.2.country <- DF[ ,11]
Tzone.moonshine <- DF[ ,12]
Tr..AP <- DF[ ,13]
Tr.zn.AP2 <- DF[ ,14]
Zip.Code.Nuts <- DF[ ,15]
Longitude <- DF[ ,16]
Latitude<- DF[ ,17]
Code <- DF[ ,18]

# create distance matrix

mat <- distm(DF[,c('Plant.lat','Plant.Long')],         DF[,c('longitude','latitude')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid) # that didnt work out

install.packages(taRifx.geo::georoute)

georoute( c("50.666 13.795", 
        "47.50827271,   16.48046829"), 
      verbose=TRUE, returntype="time", 
      service="bing" ) # but I would like to have it in driving distance
getDist(from="1 Infinity Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014", to="1600 Amphitheatre         Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043",modus="driving",get="distance")# I also tried to     make a loop, but didnt work out
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have done to overcome your problems? Which part of your code is not working? (I think you overlooked the [tour] page, also check the [help] page)

Comment: Thank you, I'm newbie here, I will do that first and then come back to you.

Comment: The [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) is the best way to do this activity, it is a service that calculates directions between locations. But like you said it has a limit of 2,500 free requests per day. But you can pay [$0.50 USD for 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits). If you have the money, then I suggest you to use this because it is the bast API to show the things that you want.

Comment: Thanks for a hint! but do you know how can I implement it to Bing maps ? and which way is the best to create a loop for it , so dont need to input 70 000 lats and longs?